# Why do not ReactJS render one component inside another?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning ReactJs. I want to use one componemt inside the other component. I looked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119579/reactjs-how-to-import-es6-custom-class?noredirect=1&lq=1), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45747521/react-js-render-one-component-in-another) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33956201/how-to-import-and-export-components-using-react-es6-webpack) and other sources, tried to apply the solutions, but they did not help me...

My *list.html* contains:

```
<body>
...
<div id="filtered_list"></div>
<script src="built/test.js"></script>
<script src="built/filteredList.js"></script>
</body>
```

*test.js*:

```
'use strict';
 const React = require('react');
 const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
 const client = require('./client');
 class Test extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {hellomsg: "one"};
    this.state.hellomsg = "I cannot get information from the REST. If you can, help me please.";
   }
render() {
    client({method: 'GET', path: '/hello-world'}).done(response => {
        //this.setState({hellomsg: response.entity});
        this.state.hellomsg = response.entity;
    });

    return (
        <p>{this.state.hellomsg}</p>
    )
}
}
ReactDOM.render(
   <Test  />,
   document.getElementById('test')
)
export default Test;
```

*filteredList.js*:

```
'use strict';
 import Test from './Test';
 const React = require('react');
 const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
 class FilteredListManger extends React.Component {
   render() {
    return (
        <p>Example Text</p> + <Test/>
    )
   }
}
ReactDOM.render(
<FilteredListManger />,
document.getElementById('filtered_list'))
```

*< Test / >* is not rendered, I have white page.

If I remove "*import Test from './Test';*" and "*+ < Test / >*" from *filteredList.js*, I can see "Example Text" text in the page, it's good.

When I open debug mode in Chrome in *Sources* tab, I do not see errors, if I open *Console* tab, I see

```
Uncaught Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
```

It leads to test.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
<Test/>,
document.getElementById('test')
)
```

I already applied solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566317/invariant-violation-registercomponent-target-container-is-not-a-dom-elem), so I do not think this is the reason.

All my *js* files are in */src/main/js*.

After *webpack* builds the project, they are in */src/resources/static/build*.

*Html*s are in */src/resources/templates*.

**What should I change here to I can use rendered result of test.js in filteredList.js?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wrap your return of FilteredListManger in a single div like this: 
`

```
<div>
 <p>Example Text</p>
 <Test/>
</div>
```

By the way, there is a lot of weird things in your code like the class to only use the render method in the FilteredListManger component...
Then, you can delete the ReactDOM.render wich is useless in the Test component

Comment: Thank you. I added divs like you suggested and deleted  ReactDOM.render from test,js. And it works!

Answer (score 1):

It's because the tag `<div id="test"></div>` doesn't exist in your HTML. For React to render the component to DOM it needs a valid DOM element. When `document.getElementById('test')` runs it returns an `undefined` object and `undefined` is not a DOM element.

Comment: Your suggestion work if I also add div tags into return of FilteredListManger. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the extra div markup you could simply use:

```
<React.Fragment>
 <p>Example Text</p>
 <Test/>
</React.Fragment>
```

Comment: Not all tool sets support this functionality yet. 
Read more about this method here: https ://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

You should move that client({method: 'GET', path: '/hello-world'}).done(response => {}) out of the render and into componentDidMount() so that it doesn't fire off on every re-render of the dom (ie if you make changes to said values).

You should also never mutate the state directly. Use this.setState(Object.assign({}, this.state, response.entity}); so that the React rendering engine can handle the re-write

Comment: Thank you for comment, I am appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can, it's not very common to have many entry points for react components in your page (The ReactDom.Render call). That is common pattern used by developers coming from Angular (as myself :) )

I would suggest you to IMPORT (or REQUIRE if you prefer) the filterList component inside  the Test component and use it there .

I very good starting point for people learning react is the **create-react-app** project. I will setup most common config and scaffold some components in a neat way: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Comment: I deleted ReactDOM.render from test.js. Thank you for the link.

Comment: Nice!! React has a big learning curve, but it's to use it in the long term... Good luck in your project! :)